# JavaScript Model Says window is Undefined

Tags: javascript

I created a new JavaScript file called truck.js and I added the following code:

```
(function(window){

  var App = window.App || {};

  function Truck(truckId, db) {
    this.truckId = truckId;
    this.db = db;
  }

  App.Truck = Truck;
  window.App = App; 

})(window);

module.exports = models;
```

After that I am importing the models in my new node file called app.js as shown below:

```
var models = require('./model')
```

I am getting the error saying "window is undefined". What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I am still having issues: Here is the code:

**customer.js:**

```
function Customer(firstName,lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

exports.Customer = Customer;
```

In app.js I use it like this:

```
var customer = require('./customer.js')
```

How do I create an object of Customer object?

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: The last line which calls the function })(window);

Comment: I don't get that error when I run it in a browser: http://jsbin.com/mokejer/1/edit?js,console … and when I run it in Node I get `ReferenceError: window is not defined`, which is subtly different from the error you are getting. Where, exactly (including operating system and version numbers!) are you running this code?

Comment: I updated the question to add more details.

Comment: my first thought was "this is a nodejs program" - but surely that's not it

Comment: oh, and there it is, literally as I wrote the previous comment, the question was updated ... it's node ... node isn't a browser so it has no `window`

Comment: Thanks! What is the recommended way of using models in node. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` is the global object provided by web browsers. Node.js is not a web browser and doesn't have a `window` object by default.

To create a module for Node, you should assign properties to the `exports` object.

```
  function Truck(truckId, db) {
    this.truckId = truckId;
    this.db = db;
  }

  exports.Truck = Truck;
```

See [*modules* in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for more information.

Comment: Still having issues! I have updated the original question.